# How can I send data to controller by dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, forms, jquery-ui

**EDIT2:** I'm trying to update my code with java, but it's not working (I suppose I miss something in controller):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var listGraphic = new Array();

  function addPhoto(u, d) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "aggiungiEpigrafe",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"graphicUrl": u, "graphicDesc": d},
        success: function(data) {
            var $url = $("<form:input>").attr({
                path: "graphicUrl",
                disabled: true
              }).html(u);
              var $desc = $("<form:input>").attr({
                path: "graphicDesc",
                disabled: true
              }).html(d);
              $("#listGraphic").append($url, "<br />", $desc, "<br /><br />");
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
           console.log(xhr.statusText);
           console.log(textStatus);
           console.log(error);
        }

    });
  }

  $("button#insertFoto").button().click(function() {
    $('#insertPhoto').dialog("open");
    return false;
  });

  $("#newPhoto").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $("#graphicUrl").val();
    var desc = $("#graphicDesc").val();
    listGraphic.push(url);
    listGraphic.push(desc);
    console.log(listGraphic);
    addPhoto(url, desc);
    $("#graphicUrl").val("");
    $("#graphicDesc").val("");
    if ($('#insertPhoto').dialog("isOpen")) {
      $('#insertPhoto').dialog("close");
    }
  });

  $('#insertPhoto').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
      "Close": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      'Insert': function() {
        $("#newPhoto").submit();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

---

**EDIT1:**
Following Twisty suggestion I uptaded the dialog in order to not have any form inside (since this dialog is already in a form): https://jsfiddle.net/e57sj6hp/18/

As Twisty was also commenting, I probably need ajax, but I have to understand how use it; I think I need to use serialize() or seralizeArray(), but I don't understand well how should the controller receive the json and use it.

---

I have a controller like this:

```
    public String myMethod(@ModelAttribute MyObject object, ModelMap model){...}
```

The object include a List of photos, and two variables url and description:

```
List<Photo> photos;
String url;
String description;
```

each photo in the list is formed by an url and a description.

In my jsp I created a dialog with jquery where a user can put an url and a description, what I want to do is to add each value into a list and send it to the controller, then clean the dialog in order to allow another submission.
I have tried a lot of but can't understand how I should do it. I'm using the spring's form and I have tried many different ways, but I think that the problem is in my javascript code. Here's one example: https://jsfiddle.net/e57sj6hp/12/

In this example the input fields and the textarea inside the dialog aren't surrounded with spring's form tags, since I've append the result inside the div and I supposed that, at the moment of the submitting, the controller should receive the data inside the form:input just created.

Comment: I suspect you need to use AJAX to send `listGraphic` along to your controller. How are other elements passed or saved to your controller?

Comment: I use an object. I searched around and I think you are right, but I totally don't know how to proceed. I understand I need serialize() or seralizeArray(), but I don't understand well how should I improve my code.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with Spring, so I may miss an element, but matching what you put in your example, I can offer some potential updates.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/e57sj6hp/16/

**HTML Updated**

```
<div id="insertPhoto" style="display:none" title="Insert a Photo">
  <form id="newPhoto">
    <label>Url:</label>
    <br/>
    <input id="graphicUrl" />
    <br/> Description:
    <br/>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="20" id="graphicDesc"></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

You cannot call `form.reset()` without a `form` element. I wrapped the the form elements in a `form`. This has the added benefit of now responding to the form being submitted, for example if the user enters a url and hits enter.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var listGraphic = new Array();

  function addPhoto(u, d) {
    var $url = $("<form:input>").attr({
      path: "graphicUrl",
      disabled: true
    }).html(u);
    var $desc = $("<form:input>").attr({
      path: "graphicDesc",
      disabled: true
    }).html(d);
    $("#listGraphic").append($url, "<br />", $desc);
  }

  $("button#insertFoto").button().click(function() {
    $('#insertPhoto').dialog("open");
    return false;
  });

  $("#newPhoto").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $("#graphicUrl").val();
    var desc = $("#graphicDesc").val();
    listGraphic.push(url);
    listGraphic.push(desc);
    console.log(listGraphic);
    addPhoto(url, desc);
    $(this)[0].reset();
    if ($('#insertPhoto').dialog("isOpen")) {
      $('#insertPhoto').dialog("close");
    }
  });

  $('#insertPhoto').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
      "Close": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      'Insert': function() {
        $("#newPhoto").submit();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Lots of little fixes and improvements here. I moved `listGraphic` out of the functions, so it can be updated more globally. This allows it to be updated and read from other callbacks.

I created the function to make it a little easier to repeat.

Now regardless of how the form is submitted, the array is updated and so is the page. The dialog is closed and it's form is reset.

**UPDATE 1**

See new jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/e57sj6hp/21/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function addPhoto(u, d) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "aggiungiEpigrafe",
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        "graphicUrl": u,
        "graphicDesc": d
      }),
      complete: function(data) {
        var $url = $("<form:input>").attr({
          path: "graphicUrl",
          disabled: true
        }).html(u);
        var $desc = $("<form:input>").attr({
          path: "graphicDesc",
          disabled: true
        }).html(d);
        $("#listGraphic").append($url, "<br />", $desc, "<br /><br />");
      }
    });
  }

  $("button#insertFoto").button().click(function() {
    $('#insertPhoto').dialog("open");
    return false;
  });

  $('#insertPhoto').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
      "Close": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      'Insert': function() {
        addPhoto($("#graphicUrl").val(), $("#graphicDesc").val());
        // Reset values
        $("#graphicUrl").val("");
        $("#graphicDesc").val("");
        // Close Dialog
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. Unfortunately is not working in my page, since the dialog is already inside a form. But surely I'm learning a lot from your explanation :)

Comment: @tina maybe I am not understanding the issue. How is the DIalog a part of a form? When I look at your example, I do not see a `form` element. Did I miss something?

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, but I don't understand how my controller should retrieve the data. If I send data from my form like this it's just taking the others input fields.

Comment: @tina I think you need to provide more of an example. It's not clear what is happening or what goal you're trying to reach.